# How to avoid an explosion of of async methods when introducing one simple await?

Tags: c#, async-await

Say for example I have a method which writes some data to a file

```
public void Foo()
{
    using (var file = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Temp\foo.txt"))
    {
        var writer = new StreamWriter(file);
        writer.WriteLine("foo");
        // some other code
    }
}
```

This introduces a small amount of lag. I decide to fix it by using asynchronous IO. I change my method to the following:

```
public async Task FooAsync()
{
    using (var file = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Temp\foo.txt"))
    {
        var writer = new StreamWriter(file);
        await writer.WriteLineAsync("foo");
        // some other code
    }
}
```

Since `async void` is said to be evil, I change the return type to `Task`.

Now in the calling method, I have an un-awaited `Task`, which is bad. So I change that method's signature to `async Task` too. Same for that method's parent. Then that method is part of an interface, which is supposed to return `void`, so I change the method in the interface to return `Task`. But there's another implementation, which now needs to return `Task` as well. I fix that, some more calling methods, etc.

Now in the end there's 20 `async` methods and 2 hours of time spent, all because I wanted to do one simple asynchronous file write.

How should I avoid this? Should I just not await a returned `Task` at some point? Or do I really need to go through all this?

Comment: the guideline states - **async all the way**. But may be a over kill

Comment: If you don't do that, your method will simply return and the caller will have no idea when the work is done. Either you need to wait for the result synchronously (which gives you the "lag"), or you need to have async all the way. "One simple await" betrays that you don't really know what happens when you use asynchronous code :) Look at how the same thing was solved before `await` came around, and marvel how easy it is to just change all the callers to `async`.

Comment: You found the primary reason not to use async. Use when you derive a tangible benefit from using it.

Answer (score 2):

> This introduces a small amount of lag. I decide to fix it by using asynchronous IO.

Asynchronous IO generally does not make your code faster, it makes it consume less resources (specifically, threads and thus also memory).

If you want to make your code more scalable or if you don't want to block the UI thread, `async` will help you. If you want to make your code faster, `async` likely won't help you at all.